# How can I upload a file to a Garmin 260?

Tags: 12.04, usb

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and trying to upload file current.gpx to `/media/GARMIN/Garmin/gpx/`.
For example, I do: `~$ cp current.gpx /media/GARMIN/Garmin/gpx/`.
Everything looks normal until I restart my GPS. Then the old file current.gpx is still there, nothing has really changed. I've tried different ways, always with the same result. Please help.

I've found out that I can upload any file to the GPS directory as long as it doesn't have a `.gpx` extension. Apparently, this is blocked by Garmin. Anybody knows of a workaround?
Ty

Answer (score 0):

Software such as [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/index.html) should help you transfer content between your GPS and the computer. I would highly recommend that you read over the **README.igc** file which explains how to convert files for your GPS. All you would need now is to download the tar.gz from the website that I linked you. Then you will need to build it. If your compilation fails, then you do not have Qt. You will have to follow [these instructions](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/Source.html)
on the website in order to compile correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe I wasn't clear. I have no problem transfering files, just files with a .gpx extension. For example,

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe I wasn't clear. I have no problem transferring files, just files with a .gpx extension. For example,
cp test.gpx /media/GARMIN/Garmin/gpx won't work,
but cp test.txt /media/GARMIN/Garmin/gpx does.